# How to give error feedback during a drag operation?

Tags: .net, wpf, drag-and-drop, adorner

I am trying to give some visual feedback to the user during a drag/drop operation.  The feedback I'm struggling with is in the case where the drag target is somehow invalid for the type of data being dragged.  I'd like there to be some feedback (during the drag) which displays a small message as to why the drag would be invalid.

I am trying to implement this by adding an adorner to the target, and have this display some message when enabled.  This seems to work ok, but isn't great.  The adorner seems like quite a low level way of doing this, as I need to implement the `OnRender` function.  I would prefer if my adorner simply contained normal WPF controls (like text labels, etc), rather than have to define my own rendering.

Is there a way of adding normal WPF controls to an adorner instead of overriding `OnRender`?

Is there something I should be using instead of adorners to give feedback to the user during a drag operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx). It could contain any number of WPF controls in it.